# jOOQ insert/update from data class

Tags: kotlin, jooq, data-class

jOOQ has this nice feature of letting you map results into a data class:

```
data class User(id: Int, email: String)

val users: List<User> = ctx.select().from(USERS).fetchInto(User::class.java)
```

Is there a similar way to write an `insert` using an automatic data mapping from a data class?

How about an `update`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse of calling the various "into" methods, such as [`ResultQuery.fetchInto(Class)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchInto(java.lang.Class)) is to load data into a record using various "from" methods, e.g. [`Record.from(Object)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#from(java.lang.Object)) or [`DSLContext.newRecord(Table, Object)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#newRecord(org.jooq.Table,java.lang.Object)), so:

```kotlin
val user: User = ...
val record: UserRecord = ctx.newRecord(USERS, user);

// Using statements
ctx.insertInto(USERS).set(record).execute();
ctx.update(USERS).set(record).where(...).execute();

// Using UpdatableRecord. See Javadoc about each one of these:
record.insert();
record.update();
record.store();
record.merge();
```

Since your data class has no notion of "dirty flag", this will always set all the values in the `UserRecord` to [`Record.changed() == true`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#changed()). You can reset the changed flag if required.

Comment: Nice! In the update case, would it need a `.where` clause or does it automatically do that e.g. with the primary key of the record? And I'm not sure I get what you mean by "dirty flag", does that mean all columns will be specified in the UPDATE statement issued regardless of whether they actually changed or not?

Comment: @JulesOlléon: Sure, you'll need a `where` clause. jOOQ only knows that you've explicitly set N column values by setting them from the data class, so your intention must have been to include them all in your update, regardless of whether the values have actually been changed.